# How to set font color in VI editor for .sc files?

Tags: vi

For example , I have ESQL/C source code saved in "test.sc"

When I open in Vi editor syntax color is always off.

I tried following command  `:syntax on` but it does not work for these types files.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i found answers here:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Forcing_Syntax_Coloring_for_files_with_odd_extensions

To change syntax color of files containing ESQL/C source code , the ":set syntax=sql" command can be used in VI.